How to Display PHP Errors in Browser? PHP 8.3 FPM, Apache 2.4.58, Ubuntu 24.04
My script displays a blank page. Two errors are logged (1 Warning, 1 Unknown error type). php.ini settings are display_errors = On, error_reporting = E_ALL. phpinfo() in the same directory (not sure that matters) shows display_errors On, error_reporting 32767 (I believe that's equivalent to E_ALL). I don't think there's any .htaccess settings interfering with these.
I just restarted php-fpm and apache and still the errors don't display.

Can you give some more details about "two errors are logged"? Where are you seeing these? What are they? What does "unknown error type" mean?

Thank you for asking those questions. I forgot there's a custom error handler in place and it needs to be configured to echo the errors to the browser. I knew I was forgetting something. So many ways to do things in PHP.

I forgot there's a custom error handler in place and it needs to be configured to echo the errors to the browser. I knew I was forgetting something. So many ways to do things in PHP.
Thanks @IMSoP
